# Python - can't import pandas

Tags: python

I get the same error whenever I want to run my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paises.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame, Series
  File "/home/david/Documents/Projetos/Intro to Data Science/pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
ImportError: cannot import name DataFrame
```

My code is:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
```

Another Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "knowingPandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/david/Documents/Projetos/Intro to Data Science/pandas.py", line 1
    adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
                            ^   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Have you tried a reinstallation of panda using `pip install pandas`?

Comment: i have, now i'm get another erro Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "knowingPandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/david/Documents/Projetos/Intro to Data Science/pandas.py", line 1
    adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
david@nofound:~/Documents/Pro

Comment: You need to recheck the source code. Consider re-analyzing `knowingpandas.py` and `pandas.py`

Comment: thanks i did it... i changed the name and it worked ...

Comment: Regarding the SyntaxError, it seems totally unrelated to the ImportError. If it's still occurring, you can ask a new question, but it might be better suited to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was with the name of the file I was trying to run. I changed the name of `pandas.py` to `pta.py`.